# Finding $\pi_q(Z)$ where Z is the orbit space of an action $\Bbb Z_2 \times S^m \times S^n \to S^m \times S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the product of the spheres $S^m \times S^n$, with $m,n>1$. Define a continuous action $\Bbb Z_2 \times S^m \times S^n \to S^m \times S^n$ with $g*(x,y)=(-x,-y)$ and let $Z$ be the orbit space of this action. Express the homotopy grops of $Z$ in terms of the homotopy groups of the spheres.

**What I know:** There's a result that says that since $\Bbb Z_2$ is a finite group and $S^m \times S^n$ is Hausdorff, then quotient map to the orbit space $p: S^m \times S^n \to Z$ is a covering space. There's another result that says that $\Bbb Z_2 \cong G(p)$, where $G(p)$ is the set of deck tranformations, and also, there's a third result that says that if $S^m \times S^n$ is simply connected, $G(p) \cong \pi_1(Z)$.

So, since $m,n>1$, $\pi_1(S^m \times S^n)=\pi_1(S^m \times S^n) = \pi_1(S^m)\times \pi_1(S^n) =0\times 0 = 0$, and we have $\pi_1(Z)=\Bbb Z_2$, but how can this be expressed in terms of $ \pi_1(S^n)=0$ and $ \pi_1(S^m)=0$? And this is only for $\pi_1(Z)$, what about for $\pi_q(Z)$ for $q>1$? I can't find any result that can be used in that case.

Comment: Not very much, take $S^n \times S^0 $, then your construction gives $S^n$ which has famously difficult homotopy groups.

Comment: In general, you get a fibration involving the quotient space and projective space.

Answer (score 1):

Well for $\pi_1$ you have an "absolute" expression, so you can consider that to be "in terms of $\pi_1(S^n), \pi_1(S^m)$" (since it's in terms of nothing, just as $f: x\mapsto 2$ expresses $2$ as a function of $x$)

As for $\pi_n,n\geq 2$, you probably have a result that relates $\pi_n(X)$ to $\pi_n(Y)$ when $Y\to X$ is a covering map, don't you ?

If you don't, a hint is that $S^n,n\geq 2$ is simply-connected, so the lifting theorem allows you to lift maps $S^n\to X$ to maps $S^n\to Y$.

Comment: Oh, yes, $\pi_n(X) \cong \pi_n(Y)$.

Comment: Then the answer will be divided into cases?

Comment: Well $2$ cases, yes

Comment: Since $\pi_q(Z) \cong \pi_q(S^n \times S^m) \cong \pi_q(S^n) \times \pi_q(S^m)$, we'd have that if $q=n,m$, $\pi_q(Z)=\Bbb Z = \pi_q(S^q)$, and $\pi_q(Z)=0$ if $q \neq n,m$, right?

Comment: The spheres have many more homotopy groups though, as Connor Malin pointed out. So you can just say $\pi_q(S^n)\times \pi_q(S^m)$, and that's pretty much the best you can get

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing it with the homology groups. At what time did we use the definiton of the action? $g*(x,y)=(-x,-y)$?

Comment: For two things : 1- it is a nice enough action to ensure that $S^n\times S^m\to Z$ is a covering map; 2- the fibers have size $2$ so you know what $\pi_1(Z)$ is (it's not $\pi_1(S^n)\times \pi_1(S^m)$ contrary to the higher $\pi_n$'s !)

Comment: But we get the same result of $\pi_q(Z)$ for any action of $\Bbb Z_2$ on $S^m \times S^n$, right?

Comment: Any free action, yes